Mongoose Error: "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"User\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)" in Next.js API Route, despite Model Import
I'm working on a Next.js API route that fetches blogs and populates the user_id field with details from the User model. This route was working yesterday but has started throwing an error:
Error


{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Couldn't fetch the blogs for some reason",
    "error": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"User\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)"
}



User Model


import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  name?: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  img?: string;
  bio?: string;
  role?: 'admin' | 'moderator' | 'user';
  created_at?: Date;
  isVerified?: boolean;
  verifyCode?: string;
  verifyCodeExpiry?: Date;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
  username: { type: String, maxlength: 50, unique: true, required: true },
  email: { type: String, maxlength: 100, unique: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, maxlength: 255, required: true },
  img: { type: String, maxlength: 255 },
  bio: { type: String },
  role: { type: String, enum: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user'], default: 'user' },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  verifyCode: { type: String, maxlength: 255 },
  verifyCodeExpiry: { type: Date },
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);



I’ve checked that:
The User model is imported. but not in use in Blog for user_id population.
Database connection is established via dbConnect() before any database operation.
getblogs/route.ts


import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { sortbyQuerySchema } from '@/schemas/blogSchema';
import dbConnect from '@/lib/db';
import Blog from '@/models/Blog.models';
import User from '@/models/User.models';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    await dbConnect();

    // Extract and validate query parameters
    const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
    const queryParam = {
      sortby: searchParams.get('sortby') // e.g., sortby=likes
    };

    const parsedVal = sortbyQuerySchema.safeParse(queryParam);

    if (!parsedVal.success) {
      const sortbyErrors = parsedVal.error.format().sortby?._errors || [];
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          success: false,
          error: parsedVal.error.message,
          message: sortbyErrors.length > 0 ? sortbyErrors.join(', ') : 'Invalid query parameters'
        },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const { sortby } = parsedVal.data;
    let blogs;

    switch (sortby) {
      case 'comments':
        blogs = await Blog.find({ comments_count: { $exists: true } }).sort({ comments_count: -1 }).populate({ path: 'user_id', select: 'name username'});
        return NextResponse.json({ success: true, message: 'Blogs sorted by comments', data: blogs }, { status: 200 });

      default:
        return NextResponse.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid sortby parameter' }, { status: 400 });
    }
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.error('Error fetching blogs', error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        success: false,
        message: "Couldn't fetch the blogs for some reason",
        error: error.message || error
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}



JSX component


'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import TrailerPost from './TrailerPost'
import axios from 'axios'


interface User {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    username: string;
}
interface blogs {
    category_id: string;
    comments_count: number;
    content: string;
    img: string;
    likes: number;
    published_at: string;
    title: string;
    user_id: User;
    __v: number;
    _id: string;
}

const TrailerPostPage = () => {

    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState<[blogs] | []>([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        const data = axios.get('/api/blogs/getblogs?sortby=latest');

        data.then((response)=>{
            setBlogs(response.data.data);
            console.log(response.data.data)
        }).catch((error: any)=>{
            console.log(error)
        })

    },[])

  return (
      <div className='flex flex-col gap-10 pt-3'>
        {
            blogs && blogs.map && blogs?.map((blog, index)=>{
                return (
                    <TrailerPost key={index} blog={blog} />
                )
            })
        }
      </div>
  )
}

export default TrailerPostPage



db.ts


import mongoose, { ConnectOptions } from 'mongoose';

const MONGODB_URI: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI || '';

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local');
}
let isConnected = false;
async function dbConnect(): Promise<mongoose.Connection> {
  if (isConnected) {
    return mongoose.connection;
  }

  const opts: ConnectOptions = {
    bufferCommands: false,
  };

try {
    const connection = await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts);
    isConnected = true;
    return connection.connection;
} catch (error: any) {
  console.error('Database connection error:', error);
  throw error;
}
}

export default dbConnect;



Expected Behavior:


{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Blogs sorted by comments",
    "data": [
        {
            "category_id": "605c72e9c23b6c001f9450e5",
            "_id": "671a936f0b782bb795652180",
            "user_id": {
                    "_id": "2o8634v2rt8r6rgr8r98",
                    "name": "Alan",
                    "username": "alanbjy"
             },
            "title": "This is a blog title for this blog 345",
            "content": "This is the content for this blog44545",
            "likes": 0,
            "comments_count": 0,
            "published_at": "2024-10-24T18:35:27.475Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}



The code I have provided was working fine yesterday.
Questions:

Is there a caching or singleton issue with Mongoose model imports in Next.js?
Why would the model suddenly become unregistered if it worked previously without issue?
Any known solutions or best practices for model registration in Next.js API routes?

Environment
next: 15.0.0-canary.174
mongoose: 8.7.2
node: v20.6.1
